# How to solve the error that occurs when npm error

Tags: javascript

[image: How to get rid of errors on npm]

I am using npm version 8.18.0 and node version 16.17.0. When I want to run code to display in the browser an error occurs.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). See also [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) from the help centre.

Comment: Make sure all dependencies that have native modules are compatible with your node version. You may have to update some. In this case probably your `node-sass` version is not compatible with node 16.17.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened to me recently. I found that this may be some third party dependencies of npm install, which need to be compiled on your machine (node-sass needs to be compiled with c++ before it can be used), or there may be problems in the download or compilation process.

1. Run `rm -rf ./node_modules` to delete node_modules folder
2. Run `npm cache clean --force` to clean npm cache file
3. Then run `npm install` to reinstall node modules or node-sass with npm install